# Trigger/run a function in client side with onChange(). Google App Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

As far as I know, google.script.run can run gs code from client side. So, is it possible to run/ trigger function in client side with onChange(e)?

I created a side bar in my spreadsheet with some html code in it. For example my html code is like below:

```
<div>
  <p id="apk">Your APK</p>
</div>
```

Then whenever someone change/edit a range in Spreadsheet, it will automatically get that value and change my paragraph's(html) value to whatever value users put in the range.

```
function changeApk(){
  document.getElementById("apk").innerHtml = getApk;
}
```

My gs code :

```
function onChange(e){
  var activeSheet = e.source.getActiveSheet(); 
  var lr = activeSheet.getRange("F11").getDataRegion().getLastRow();
  var getApk = activeSheet.getRange(lr,6).getValue();
  return getApk;
}
```

As you see, I tried to get the getApk value and update that in my paragraph tags. And I want it to happen automatically after users change/edit the range without clicking any button in html code. And now i'm stuck here. Any idea how to do it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does `return getApk;` do?  There's nothing to return to.  It was called by a trigger.  In answer to your question, not directly it must first be called from the client.

Comment: @MetaMan it will get the value from sheet and return the value to client side.  Oh I see, I though the same too. Thanks!

Comment: No it won't because in was called by a trigger so there's nothing to return it too. Perhaps I'm wrong in assuming that it's called by a trigger. Is the onChange(e) function called by a trigger?  If it is then there is nothing to return anything too.

Comment: And there is no document object model on the server side.  It's just doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You cannot change the clientside of an Apps Script project on server-side trigger

What you can do instead is web polling - that is refreshing your clientside content in close intervals by calling `google.script.run` with [setInterval()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp).

Sample:

code.gs

```js
function getValue(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("XXXXXX").getSheetByName("YYY"); 
  var lr = sheet.getRange("F11").getDataRegion().getLastRow();
  var getApk = sheet.getRange(lr,6).getValue();
  return getApk;
}
```

index.html

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <script>
  function polling(){
    setInterval(myFunction,2000);
   }
  function myFunction(){
    var lob = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(changeApk).getValue();    

  }
function changeApk(getApk){
  document.getElementById("apk").innerHtml = getApk;
}
  </script>
  <body onload="polling()">
  <div>
    <p id="apk">Your APK</p>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Depending on your implementation you will additionaly need a `doGet()` function to deploy a [WebApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) or create an HTML output for your [sidebar](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#custom_sidebars).

Comment: @ ziganotschka thanks! but isn't it will cause the Spreadsheet to lag if i have multiple user who using the sheet?

Comment: Maybe slightly, but you can reduce the impact by polling at less frequent intervals (e.g. every 10s instead of every 2).